# Can an ARINC 429 controller set to receive messages on high-speed (100kHz) see 12.5kHz messages?

Tags: arinc-429

I am working with an ARINC 429 controller which is currently set to receive messages at 100kHz. When the transmission line sends messages that are 12.5kHz (standard ARINC 429 low speed) the controller can see them.

Is this normal for an ARINC 429 controller?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is normal for an ARINC 429 receiver. The clocking for ARINC 429 is built into the transmission data, with the bipolar Return to Zero format having a Null for the last half of each bit time and requiring 4 bit times of null (0) voltage between labels. This lets the receiver adjust to the data rate automatically.

Comment: At first glance, it seems like some curious behavior. Right now I am developing an API for an ARINC controller in C#. This is one of the things I encountered while testing the different speed settings of the controller. Thanks.